# Windows 2012 fonts gone. Only Wingdings

Tags: linux, windows, debian, rdp

So I did an RDP to my server, using a Jessie distro with Vinagre, characters were weird (see picture) and then, everyone who connects sees the same problem, how did this hapend and how can I fix it? Because server is totally useless...

Everything worked before I connect, now we can't work :S

[image]

Comment: What's in the C:\Windows\Fonts\ directory? Are other fonts present? Incidentally, that does not appear to be Windows built-in Wingdings.ttf glyphs.

Comment: Every font was missing, how the hell they got deleted without interaction?? It doesn't make sense at all. My pals are using Ubuntu instead of Debian Jessie and everything worked great for them until I RDP'd...

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this is a serious problem for you, but I find this hilarious. Literally laughing out loud. :D

Comment: Yea so funny that we now need to reinstall whole server because when we try to restore fonts, it deletes them automatically. They keep blaming my RDP connection for that, but it's impossible, because I'd only connected via RDP, saw thoose symbols and close my connection because I couldn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this could be related to the Windows updates: [Windows 8.1 - All fonts deleting on reboot](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/windows-81-all-fonts-deleting-on-reboot/60e7ad50-149c-4f94-b1a6-8e013aeba40b)

> Upon further investigation, ALL of my fonts are completely gone and
>   any installed font (including Segoe UI) are deleted after I reboot.

Try the solution from [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2982791) and see, if it works for you.